# Adding a username/password to a URL

Tags: url, authentication, autologin

I have a web address that I'm trying to add functionality for username/password to be included.

This is not a super secure website, but it is on an 'https' because other than the one username/password that's used by everybody in the organization, it's very secure to the outside world. It's an online school website portal login.

I've tried this...

```
Username:PassWord1@university.edu/portal/server.pt
```

and this...

```
https://xxx.university.edu/portal/server.pt?userName=SomeUser&password=somePassword
```

(Thanks Ali B)

...but that doesn't work. My understanding is that MS fixed a bug that allowed this to happen after IE6.

Any chance of a workaround out there?

Reason is that after so many people try to log into it, it locks out anybody trying to attempt a login, and when the whole organization can't log in, that's a problem.

### Thoughts?

**Edit:** It should be known that this address will be accessed on IE8 only. It's our corporate browser.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft officially stopped supporting username/password combos in URLs. IE 6 was the last IE to support this function.

[http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;[LN];834489](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;%5bLN%5d;834489)

Comment: Interesting article. Thanks Steve.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why you wouldn't use query parameters, such as https://xxx.university.edu/portal/server.pt?userName=SomeUser&password=somePassword ? Most web frameworks have a reasonable mechanism for extracting query parameters from the request.

Comment: I've tried that too (sorry... forgot to mention it). The page shows up, but doesn't fill in the appropriate fields. Tried in IE8 and latest versions of Chrome/Firefox... doesn't work there either. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you describe what framework you are using to serve this page please? The query parameters I mention are only going to be useful if your code is looking for them.

Comment: Framework? What do you mean by that? The URL is built like this https://campus.university.edu/portal/server.pt, but I am trying to redirect someone from an HTML page to that site, and when the user arrives at the site, the Username/Password are already entered. All the user has to do is click Log In, and they're in...

Comment: This is the HTML for the username box -   `<input type="text" alt="ptmsgs_portalbrowsingmsgs string 633" size="30" class="formInputBoxText" name="in_tx_username" id="pt-login-username-textbox" onkeypress="return executeViaEnter(event);" value="">`

Comment: And this is for the password box - `<input type="password" alt="ptmsgs_portalbrowsingmsgs string 634" size="30" class="formInputBoxText" name="in_pw_userpass" id="pt-login-password-textbox" onkeypress="return executeViaEnter(event);" value="">`

Comment: I see. I am not sure if the following change will work but worth a try:  https://xxx.university.edu/portal/server.pt?in_tx_username=SomeUser&in_pw_userpass=somePassword .

Comment: Unfortunately I have no more ideas. The best thing to do is to launch webdev developer tools (e.g. in Firefox, you have Tools -> Web Developer -> Web Console) and then try to use the page while manually typing in the information. This should show you the REST operations that your browser conducts to send the login information to the web application.

Comment: What if I were to contain the schhol login site on our intranet site, inside an iframe? Would that make any difference?